# Getting Excel sheet cell value next to a merged column

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet formatted as the image below.
[image: Excel Sheet Image]

I would like to retrieve the list of cell texts next to a merged column. I am thinking something of this kind. My idea is to get the total number of merged cells and then iterate over the next set of cells. I cannot find any method in `Range` that returns the total number of cells in a merged cell. The properties `EntireRow` and `EntireColumn` doesn't give the total number of cells merged. Any hints would be helpful.

```
List<String> GetNextTexts(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range)
{}
```

**Examples**

- `GetNextTexts(rangeTest)` should return `{TestRx, TestSPC}`
- `GetNextTexts(rangeTestRx)` should return `{P4_7, P0_0, P0_14, P3_2}`
- `GetNextTexts(rangeTestSPC)` should return `{P2_4}`

Answer (score 1):

Here are some `Range` properties that can be useful (assuming rangeTest is in `B2:B6`) :

`rangeTest = Range["B2"].MergeArea` gives the range of the merged cell Test - `B2:B6`

`rangeTest.Rows.Count` and `rangeTest.Count` give the number of rows and number of cells  - 5

`rangeTest.Offset[0, 1]` gives the range `C2`, and `.MergeArea` of that gives the rangeTestRx.

`rangeTestRx.Count` can be used to get the number of cells in rangeTestRx (4), and compare that to the number of cells in rangeTest to check if there is another cell below rangeTestRx.

`rangeTestRx.Offset[4, 0]` can be used to get the Range below rangeTestRx - `C6` and so on.

Comment: The problem here is `rangeTest.Rows.Count` and `rangeTest.Count` always returns 1.Is there any way to find the actual number of rows/columns merged?

Comment: @FaisalM the count should be on the `.MergeArea` range. I don't get 1 when I try it on a merged cell